# Provide names for (non-by-reference) j-expression as character vector

Tags: r, data.table

In a `data.table`, for non-by-reference j-experssions, I would like to be able to set the resulting column name(s) using a character vector.

As I am in a group-by setting, I cannot use the by-reference syntax, because this will introduce many duplicated rows. Since a j-expression in this case can be specified as a list, my solution is using `stats::setNames()`. This however gives me a message (which might even be turned into a warning in the future). How do I achieve my goal without `data.table` complaining about efficiency?

```r
my_fun <- function(tbl, new_names = c("mean", "var")) {
  tbl[, setNames(list(mean(b), var(b)), new_names), by = "a", verbose = TRUE]
}

dt <- data.table::data.table(
  a = sample(letters[1:5], 1e3, replace = TRUE),
  b = rnorm(1e3)
)

my_fun(dt)
```

While the results are as intended:

```r
   a        mean       var
1: a -0.04117688 1.1080222
2: e  0.00158758 1.1629461
3: c -0.04328856 0.9848994
4: d -0.04832948 0.8760644
5: b  0.10856561 0.9313874
```

I would like to get rid of the following message:

> Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... The result of j is a named list. It's very inefficient to create the same names over and over again for each group. When j=list(...), any names are detected, removed and put back after grouping has completed, for efficiency. Using j=transform(), for example, prevents that speedup (consider changing to :=). This message may be upgraded to warning in future.

Comment: Just use data.table's setnames function after the by operation?

Answer (score 0):

This changed it to "Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.000sec":

```
my_fun <- function(tbl, new_names = c("a", "mean", "var")) {
  setNames(tbl[, list(mean(b), var(b)), by = "a", verbose = TRUE], new_names)
}

my_fun(dt)
```

Comment: Don't use base setNames on a data.table. Use data.table::setnames.